# ColdFusion/Ajax verify math on form fields before submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, coldfusion

I have 3 fields that need to be tied together. I need them to be verified before submission.

```
<cfinput type="text" name="cost_per" validate="float" validateat="onsubmit">
<cfinput type="text" name="case_qty" validate="float" validateat="onsubmit">
<cfinput type="text" name="case_cost" validate="float" validateat="onsubmit">
```

**[cost_per] x [case_qty] = [case_cost]**

I need the submit button disabled until the math is correct.

i.e. **[cost_per]$5.25 x [case_qty] 12 = [case_cost] $63.00** if the math checks out, allow user to submit the form.

Because of where this is being implemented, I have to allow the user to modify all three fields.

Not sure if it matters, but there are two more fields, `qty_received`, `qty_rejected`. The math involved with these fields will be done after submission.

Comment: Take a look at using [jQuery Validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org) - a pretty powerful and easy to use client side validation plugin for jQuery. it allows you to set up custom validations, which, it seems you will need to accomplish what you need. You should still do server side validation, however.

Comment: If you want to hide the submit button hidden until the math is correct, you'll have to look at the validateat attribute of your cfinput tags.

Comment: I should have added...stop using `cfinput`, use the real HTML tags and learn how to do this the real/right way.

Comment: The right way?  Is there anything other than your dislike of cfinput that makes it the wrong way?

Comment: The use of `cfinput` alone is enough to make it 'wrong'